# MSSQL NVarChar(1) to .Net Char

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, casting

In my MSSQL Database is a field of type `nvarchar(1)`, meaning it supports 2 byte unicode. In my application I read that field and store it into a Char variable like so:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dataTbl
    Dim SomeVar As Char? = If(IsDBNull(row(RowNames.FieldName)), Nothing, CChar(row(RowNames.FieldName)))
Next row
```

In the field in the database in the relevant row is an 'A', so it should be `0x 0041`

However when I print the char for testing, it gives me �, a black diamond with a questionmark in the browser (it is a web app.) or "\u0000" when using newtonsoft serializer.

So what type of variable do I need to write this into and how do I do the cast?

**Edit:**
It turns out the error was me fetching the wrong data.

Comment: .NET strings are Unicode too. There's no need for conversion at all. If you get a � it means that you tried to read the string as *ANSI* using the wrong codepage, or that the data was mangled before it was even stored in SQL Server

Comment: BTW `CChar` is a compatibility function for old VB6 code. If that field contains a *string*, `row(RowNames.FieldName)` will return it. All you need to do is cast it to a String, definitely not *Char*

Comment: You should replace your code with `Dim someVar As String=DirectCast(row(RowNames.FieldName), String)` or `row(RowNames.FieldName).ToString()`

Comment: will String.DirectCast(row("Field")) also work if row("Field") is DBNull?

Comment: An `NCHAR(1)` can be read as a `Char`. An `NCHAR(x)` should be read as a string. `row.Field(Of Char)(RowNames.FieldName)` should do for a single character; `row.Field(Of String)(RowNames.FieldName)` for strings. `DataRow.Field` (actually `DataRowExtensions`) knows about `NULL`, so make it `Of Char?` if you need that.

Comment: it is `nvarchar(1)`

Comment: @FalcoGer in that case it *can't* be read as a Char. It's a variable-length string with a maximum length of 1 that can easily be empty

Comment: Dim strTemp As String = If(IsDBNull(row(RowNames.FieldName)), Nothing, row.Field(Of String)(RowNames.FieldName))  
                Dim varToUse As Char? = If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTemp) AndAlso strTemp.Length = 1, strTemp(0), Nothing)

Comment: `Dim c As Char? = row.Field(Of String)(RowNames.FieldName)?.FirstOrDefault()` .

Comment: I think you can easily read the filed from the database as `String` and then pick up the first item from the _string variable_ finally does the desired work on that type. some times we have to think things as simple as possible.